# Doing Count Function to Queue

Tags: c#, queue

I'm trying to write code which counts the numbers in the queue. The problem is that I remove the items in the original queue and I would rather save it as it is.

This is my code:

```
public static int Count(Queue<int> q) //checks how many items there's in the argument queue.
    {
        Queue<int> pos = q;
        Queue<int> qtemp1 = new Queue<int>();
        int counter = 0;
        while (pos != null && pos.IsEmpty())
        {
            qtemp1.Insert(pos.Remove());
            counter++;

        }
        return counter;
}
```

Comment: I found a little solution - in the end of the function, right before the Return line, I did while loop which insert back the items to the original Queue.

Answer (score 0):

Try `q.count`

```
public static int Count(Queue<int> q)
{
    return q.Count;
}
```

Comment: Impossible. count function requires q as argument...
The code is right, it does return how many items there are in the queue, the problem is that the function remove the items when it counts them.

Comment: Wait, what? Of course you need to specify what Queue you are counting from, in this case `q` (just as you have in your question!). All Queue.Count does is return the number of items in your Queue as an integer, which based on your question is exactly what you are asking for. Queue.Count won't remove any items in your Queue.

Comment: I know, it shouldn't remove but it is. If you'll debug the code you'll see that the q is empty after I'm debugging the function

Comment: You must have an issue somewhere else in your code. I just tested it, and my Queue didn't lose any items after `q.Count`. Feel free to use `MessageBox.Show(q.Count.ToString());` multiple times in a row to check that the integrity of your Queue is maintained. You could also use a `foreach` loop to peek at all of the items in your Queue.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the Queue.Remove()... What's your Queue.Remove?

Comment: I didn't use `Queue.Remove()` in my code. As you can see in my answer, I replaced your entire function with just `return q.Count;`. If you _are_ trying to remove the item from your Queue when transferring it to a new one, you'll want to use `Queue.Dequeue()`.

Comment: Ohh I understand what did u do.. U used the original Queue.count(), I don't wanna use it, I made my own count function. It's a task from school. Also, when I tried to use your answer I got this error: 'Queue<int>' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument of type 'Queue<int>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I assumed you were designing a Windows Forms Application - my bad. Is your program a console application? If so, try `Console.WriteLine(q.Count.ToString());`

Comment: Yeah I'm using Console Application sorry.
I tried to do the ToString, I get this error: 

Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.

Comment: Is that error occurring on the line with the code `Console.WriteLine(q.Count.ToString());`? Because I've never encountered that error before when using `ToString()`.

Comment: Yeah. Okay I'll explain better - we've learned today Queue<T> on c#, my teacher gave us question to write the Queue class by ourselves so I did. Next, she asked us to write function which get existing Queue and  return how many items there are in the Queue without change the given Queue. That's what I did but I did it only with changing the existing Queue.

Comment: If you aren't allowed to use `Queue.Count`, I'd approach it using a `foreach` loop. Since it's a homework assignment, I'll leave it at that to get you started.

Comment: How should I use the foreach loop?

Comment: Still hapenning... When I'm debugging the function it clears all the items in the queue (q). I need to keep it as it was